# leaflet poligon draw and kml load

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

new leaflet user here. 
basically I need to achieve 2 things:
1.draw a poligon (with my mouse) on a lealet map and be able to edit it 
2. import/export kml data from KML into/outof a lealet map.
I have some basic questions:
1. can this be achieved easaly with leaflet only? (no plugins)
2. when using plugins: like leaflet-kml/omnivore/filelayer/draw/tokml etc I know I can achieve what I need. but all these plugins latest tagged version is from years ago. I am not sure if its ok to use them and how come there isnt a newer version (maybe there's no need for a new one)

I would appreciate your answers very much
 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make all your drawings in Leaflet, but with some exceptions, for example; difference, polygon merge-transfer, autotrace etc. The plugins turf and geoman you can use in your situations will be successful for you.

Among the kml import-export operations, as you mentioned, tokml will work for the export operation, although its last update is outdated. For the import process, I suggest you search for the KML plugin included in the leaflet, it will be successful for you.